# Set up a button under an image

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a custom script from the https://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/ website. I have implemented correctly in my website, the problem is that i am trying to have a button under an image. Right now there is an "alt" with a text. How to insert a button on there? I have tried many things but non of them are working. Here is an image that shows how it looks, what i am trying to do is set up a button where it says "cool down"

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fashion photography " >                                     
                                <a href="img/tshirt.jpg" data-rel="lightcase"class="portfolio_item" >                                                  
                                    <img src="img/men.jpeg" alt="this t-shirt is awesome" class="img-responsive">                                                                          
                                    <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
                                        <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                                            <div class="item_info"> <span>Men Tennis Style </span> <em>Fashion</em> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for positioning the button over the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>prasad</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <style>
  .photography {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
  }
  .photography img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .photography .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #884992;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .photography .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 fashion photography container">
  <a href="https://img.romwe.com/images/romwe.com/201701/1483596883558198680_thumbnail_800x.webp" data-rel="lightcase"class="portfolio_item" >                                                  
   <img src="https://img.romwe.com/images/romwe.com/201701/1483596883558198680_thumbnail_800x.webp" alt="this t-shirt is awesome" class="img-responsive">                         
   <button class="btn">Cool down</button>
   <div class="portfolio_item_hover">
             <div class="portfolio-border clearfix">
                 <div class="item_info"><span>Men Tennis Style </span> <em>Fashion</em></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```